# Using <p> tags wrong, what else to do

Tags: html

I have this little piece of code and I often run into this problem knowing it's bad practice and I seek to find a better way to optimize this code.

```
<p>Register a house <a href="register.php">here</a>.
<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);" class="login"></p>
```

As you can see, I have wrapped the whole text in a `<p>` tag which is obviously bad practice but I need the two things to stand next to each other, and putting them on the same paragraph is surely the easiest way, but what ways would be best practice?

I have considered using a table for this, but using tables for things that are not meant to be a part of a table seems like bad practice too, lot's of code and it might be confusing.

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is this a bad practice?

Comment: Who said this is bad practice? You can use label `<p> <label></label> <input></p>`

Comment: what can't use `<div>` or `<section>`?

Comment: You might want to go through inline display type: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/30-the-css-layout-model-boxes-border/#elementtypesdisplay

Comment: @user3287771 use a `<span>` instead of a. `<p>` tag it may solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you'd think a `<p>` is bad practice. But:

- You can always use elements like `<div>` and `<section>` if it suits you better.
- Use `<label>` elements to associate labels for inputs. If done properly, you can have a nice effect when clicking on the label to focus on the corresponding input.
- Easy rule to remember: An inline(-block) element can always be placed in a block element

Answer (score 1):

The correct and most semantic way to do this would likely be:

```
<form>
    <label>Your Label Here</label>
    <input type="text" />
</form>
```

However, there really isn't anything wrong with how you're doing it. If it works, it works. Cleanliness is for other people or for yourself if you have to revisit the code a long time from now.

Hopefully this helps you have cleaner code!

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap it in a span or div if you don't want to use a paragraph:

```
<div>Register a house <a href="register.php">here</a>.
<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);" class="login">
</div>
```

The input would also best be in a  - this can be outside of the  or

[It seems to work the same](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/tbg6xcw3stg0o8b/a.html)